# Deploy worklight application using Ant tasks

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Ant to deploy my application to the production application server(WebSphere). 
I use the sample configuration file located in the ${WORKLIGHT_INSTALL_DIR}\configuration-samples folder. the configuration file is marked as suitable for Websphere liberty and Apache derby. 
On the configuration sections i change the value (and only this value according with the documentation IBM) of the path element tag (below the code reported).

```
 <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
<classpath>
  <pathelement location="C:\workspace\jQueryMobileApplication\bin\jQueryMobileApplication.war"/>
</classpath>
```

Setting as location my application war's path. The build.xml file is located in the same folder of my project's war file. 
When i type the command :

```
ant -f <filename>.xml
```

i get this exception:

```
Buildfile: C:\IBM\WorklightSRV\WorklightServer\configure-liberty-derby.xml
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties. It could not be found.
```

I'm a newbie with Worklight development(and also with Ant Deployment), so i appreciate any help even if this may be a trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath is for the worklight-ant.jar to define the tasks to ant
ex.

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="./lib/worklight-ant.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

After the ant tasks are loaded you can use one of the worklight ant tasks to do your commands
ex.

```
<echo>Export war file</echo>
        <war-builder projectfolder="./<ProjectDirectory>" destinationfolder="bin/war" warfile="bin/Application.war.${env}" classesFolder="<ProjectDirectory>/bin/classes" />
```

From what i know this will create the war for you but you will have to deploy it manually.

Comment: Thank you tik27, i changed that stuff and now i can build it. anyway i'm facing another problem, i didn't set the 'websphereapplicationserver installdir' and so its value is still the default one(that is /n/java/webservers/was-liberty-8.5-express). in which appplication server's folder should i install the application?

Comment: i tried with C:\Programfiles\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer or C:\Programfiles\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\newApp but it doesn't work yet

Comment: Are you running full Websphere or websphere liberty?

Comment: my app is running WebSphere liberty, i set the directory of websphere liberty profile and it works. thank you!